# terraform, select content inside a double nested map

Tags: terraform

i would like to select the content of a nested map depending on its name

In this exemple for exemple i would like to select values inside "secure"

```
  + zone_list_policy_rules  = {
      + common         = {}
      + data           = {}
      + secure         = {
          + test_zone_to_zone  = {
              + application = [
                  + "TCP_22",
                  + "TCP_100-200",
                ]
              + destination = [
                  + "titi-01",
                ]
              + from_zone   = [
                  + "secure",
                ]
              + source      = [
                  + "toto-01",
                ]
              + to_zone     = [
                  + "data",
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

To get a variable like

```
      + secure         = {
          + test_zone_to_zone  = {
              + application = [
                  + "TCP_22",
                  + "TCP_100-200",
                ]
              + destination = [
                  + "titi-01",
                ]
              + from_zone   = [
                  + "secure",
                ]
              + source      = [
                  + "toto-01",
                ]
              + to_zone     = [
                  + "data",
                ]
            }
        }
```

i can select like this:

`test = { for k, v in local.zone_list_policy_rules :  k => v if k == "secure"}`

But can figure out to remove the top level
Help is very appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just index the map with the key name and build a new map:

```
locals {
  zone_list_policy_rules = {
    common = {}
    data   = {}
    secure = {
      test_zone_to_zone = {
        application = [
          "TCP_22",
          "TCP_100-200",
        ]
        destination = [
          "titi-01",
        ]
        from_zone = [
          "secure",
        ]
        source = [
          "toto-01",
        ]
        to_zone = [
          "data",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  secure = {secure: local.zone_list_policy_rules["secure"]}
}
```

```bash
$ terraform console
> local.secure
{
  "secure" = {
    "test_zone_to_zone" = {
      "application" = [
        "TCP_22",
        "TCP_100-200",
      ]
      "destination" = [
        "titi-01",
      ]
      "from_zone" = [
        "secure",
      ]
      "source" = [
        "toto-01",
      ]
      "to_zone" = [
        "data",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My god, i was so focusing trying to solve it with a  for loop that i didnt see it so simple, thanks a lot !

Comment: @lotusnoir you're welcome. if you found the answer useful please upvote the answer too

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to make it !

```
  test = merge([
    for zone, rules in local.zone_list_policy_rules:
      { for sk, sv in rules : sk => sv if zone == "secure"}                                                                                                                                                
  ]...)
```

Comment: This is awfully, pointlessly complex